# how to generate all legal statements from ebnf?

Tags: ebnf

I have an EBNF that defines a grammar. The rules of the grammar allow around 8000 permutations that are legal statements.

Is there any utility that can automatically generate legal statements from an EBNF?

Comment: If the grammar allows repetition (e.g. { and }), there may be an infinite number of legal statements.

Comment: In this case the grammar doesn't allow repetition, or it least it shouldn't.That would be one benefit of having a utility generate legal statements, if the utility generated a large number of statements without completing I'd know there was an error in the grammar.